# Django Export Excel -- Category based on count

Tags: python, django

**Edited based on comment**

I am using Django and want to export it in excel. How can you do count based on occurences of the category. How can you put unique values of Accident Causation?

Accident Causation -- Severity
Severity has three options: Severity 1, Severity 2, Severity 3

The excel should look like this

```
Accident Causation | Severity 1| Severity 2 | Severity 3
Accident Causation1| 20        | 10         | 0
Accident Causation2| 0         | 5          | 0
```

**Model**

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
user_report = models.OneToOneField(UserReport, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
accident_factor = models.ForeignKey(AccidentCausation, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
accident_subcategory = models.ForeignKey(AccidentCausationSub, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
collision_type = models.ForeignKey(CollisionType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
collision_subcategory = models.ForeignKey(CollisionTypeSub, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
crash_type = models.ForeignKey(CrashType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
weather = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=WEATHER, blank=True, null=True)
light = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=LIGHT, blank=True, null=True)
severity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=SEVERITY, blank=True, null=True)
movement_code = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**Views**

```
def export_accidentcausation_xls(request):
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="accident_causation.xls"'


wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
ws = wb.add_sheet('Accident Causation')

alignment = xlwt.Alignment()

alignment.horz = xlwt.Alignment.HORZ_LEFT
alignment.vert = xlwt.Alignment.VERT_TOP
style = xlwt.XFStyle() # Create Style
style.alignment = alignment # Add Alignment to Style

# Sheet header, first row
row_num = 0

font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
font_style.font.bold = True

header_font = xlwt.Font()

# Header font preferences
header_font.name = 'Times New Roman'
header_font.height = 20 * 15
header_font.bold = True

# Header Cells style definition
header_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
header_style.font = header_font 


body_font = xlwt.Font()

# Body font preferences
body_font.name = 'Arial'
body_font.italic = True


borders = xlwt.Borders()
borders.left = 1
borders.right = 1
borders.top = 1
borders.bottom = 1
header_style.borders = borders

# body cell name style definition
body_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
body_style.font = body_font 



columns = ['Username', 'First name', 'Middle name', 'Last name', 'Email address', 'Mobile Number', 'Birthday', 'Role', 'Status', 'Last Login', 'Created At', 'Updated At']

for col_num in range(len(columns)):
    ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], header_style)
    ws.col(col_num).width = 7000

    

# Sheet body, remaining rows
# font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
# rows1 = AccidentCausation.objects.all()
rows = IncidentGeneral.objects.all().values_list('accident_factor__category', 'accident_subcategory')
rows = rows.annotate(
     severity1=Count('severity', only=Q(1)),
    severity2=Count('severity', only=Q(2)),
    severity3=Count('severity', only=Q(3))
)
# rows = [[x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime) else x for x in row] for row in rows ]
for row in rows:
    row_num += 1
    for col_num in range(len(row)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], body_style)


wb.save(response)
return response
```

**URL**

```
urlpatterns = [  
    path('generate_report', views.generate_report, name='generate_report'),
    path('generate_report/export_users_xls', views.export_users_xls, name='export_users_xls'),
    path('generate_report/export_accidentcausation_xls', views.export_accidentcausation_xls, name='export_accidentcausation_xls'),
]
```

Comment: Can you add your query code ?

Comment: @LucasGrugru I added below but it cant seem to work. Thank you

rows = IncidentGeneral.objects.all().values_list('accident_factor__category').count('severity')
    # rows = [[x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime) else x for x in row] for row in rows ]
    for row in rows:
        row_num += 1
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], body_style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you can make a queryset like this i think:

```
queryset = IncidentGeneral.objects.all().values('accident_factor')
queryset = queryset.annotate(
    severity1=Count('severity', filter=Q(severity=1)),
    severity2=Count('severity', filter=Q(severity=2)),
    severity3=Count('severity', filter=Q(severity=3))
)

for item in queryset:
    print(item.accident_factor, item.severity1, item.severity2, item.severity3)
```

Comment: There is another problem when I export it to excel the count is the same across the columns. How can I make it count of accident who has severity1 only

Comment: I make mistake. we have to use the `filter` keyword parameter for `Count` aggregate instead of `only`. you can read the documentation of the function you are using here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/